# GridView in UpdatePanel adds extra rows when sorting another grid

Tags: gridview, updatepanel

I'm a seeing some weird behavior that i have never seen before.

I have two grid in separate UpdatePanels. I can page and sort each without any problems.

Each grid is set for 10 per page.

If the first grid (13 records) is paged to the second page and then i go down to the second grid (14 records) and page to the next page and the first grid adds a bunch of empty rows to the grid so it is full to show 10. There is no data in the rows...just empty rows. Each grid does this on paging and sorting.

Ive stepped through the code and the the loading of the other grids never happens so it tells my AJAX is doing something to add the 'phantom' rows to the grid.

Any ideas why or ways to debug this?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know whether you got a fix for this or not.  I had a similar problem with a gridview involving a checkbox in a templatefield.  Whenever I clicked the checkbox on a page with less than the defined page size, the gridview would redraw itself with as many rows as was defined by the page size.  So I'd end up with several empty rows after the last row of valid data.

I solved this problem by disabling the viewstate on the gridview (i.e. `EnableViewState="false"`) and everything worked out fine.